# IIS Web Site Application -> Manage Application -> Advanced Settings -> Physical Path Credentials will not accept Group Managed Service Account

Tags: windows, web, iis

If I try to set the Physical Path Credentials for an application in a IIS (v10) Web Site to a Group Managed Service Account, it accepts the account name, which terminates with a "$", and grays out the Password field.  I click OK in the "Set Credentials" form,  which returns me to the "Connect As" form where I also click OK, which returns me to the Advanced Settings form, but when I click OK on that form I get the "Red X" with the message "The specified password is invalid".  How do I get the Physical Path Credentials to accept a Group Managed Service Account?  Shouldn't the "Advanced Settings" form offer "Service" as one of the options in the drop-down for the "Physical Path Credentials Logon Type" option?  Is the fact that the Type does not offer "Service" the cause of the problem?  Or will a Group Managed Service Account not work for Physical Path Credentials and if not, why not?

Comment: In the `User name` input box, type the name of the domain name, backslash, and Managed Service Account with “$” add the end, and  leave the Password and Confirm password text boxes empty. Look at this link: https://hansstan.wordpress.com/2017/07/05/using-group-managed-service-accounts-with-iis/

Comment: Yes, I followed that argument and those instructions. It does not speak to the “Physical Path Credentials” of a particular application served by the Web site. The “Physical Path Credentials” are distinct from any thing in that post.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the appcmd.exe command line: `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:applicationPools /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.userName:DOMAIN\USER_NAME /[name='APP_POOL_NAME'].processModel.password:PASSWORD`

Refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771170(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I have lost my test environment so it might be a while before I can try that but I appreciate the suggestion.  Seems like an idea worth pursuing.

Comment: Got my test environment back.  I could not identify the syntax needed to do this with appcmd.exe but I found a PowerShell command that works:

Comment: Set-WebConfiguration "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='WebSiteName']/application[@path='/AppDirName']/VirtualDirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{username='DOMAIN\GMSA-Name$'}   This command will successfully update the applicationHost.config file but it will also successfully update it for a bogus username value.  So there is no validation being done. But the problem has only moved downfield a yard or two because IIS doesn't recognize the GMSA.

Comment: After updating the config with the GMSA and trying to access the application, IIS reports: "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error".... "Can not log on locally to <app-path> as user <DOMAIN\GMSA-NAME> with virtual directory password."  BOTTOM LINE: IIS does not support the use of a GMSA for the Physical Path Credentials of an Application.  Seems like a bug.... how do I get it in front of Microsoft?